# jQuery onClick navigation tab - need to pull in body content

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I have a pages that has 3 tabs at the top of the page, which need to have a styling element applied to them, when they are clicked. I have done this using the .toggleClass('active'); function and then styled the 'active' class in css. This bit is fine and working as I need it to.

However the next bit I need to get working is that for each tab click, a related tab of content is displayed in the body of the content in the page.

So I have this so far.

```
   <ul>

        <li class="active">Primary</li>
        <li>Secondary</li>
        <li>Tertiary</li>

   </ul>
```

```
   <div class="tabs">

     <div class="slate">Content1</div>
     <div class="slate">Content2</div>
     <div class="slate">Content3</div>

   </div>
```

So I need that when an li is clicked it applies the class active (i have this working), and then it also shows the content from the relevant div within the 'tabs' container div. So if primary was clicked in the ul - it would display the content from the first child in the tabs div.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you have control over your html then you can apply IDs on your li elements and same ID's values should be applied on the tab contents as a class name, That way you can get the id to target to the class name to toggle:

```js
$('li').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings('li').removeClass('active');
  $('.slate.'+this.id).show().siblings('.slate').hide();
});
```

```css
li{list-style:none;}
.slate{display:none;}
.slate.active{display:block}
li.active{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>

  <li id='primary' class="active">Primary</li>
  <li id='secondary'>Secondary</li>
  <li id='tertiary'>Tertiary</li>

</ul>
<div class="tabs">

  <div class="slate primary active">Content1</div>
  <div class="slate secondary">Content2</div>
  <div class="slate tertiary">Content3</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfect :D

Answer (score 2):

Mark the content panes with ids or classes that indicate which tab they correspond to. Then show/hide the content panes on tab click.

HTML:

```
<div class="tabs">
    <div class="slate tab-1">Content1</div>
    <div class="slate tab-2">Content2</div>
    <div class="slate tab-3">Content3</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("tab-selector").on("click", function () {
    var index = $(this).index() + 1;
    $("div.slate").hide();
    $("div.tab-" + index).show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, however, I can't get it working quite right.            I have this;                                                             $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".tab_navigation ul li").click(function(){
            
            if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){
                $(this).toggleClass("active").siblings().removeClass('active');

                var index = $(this).index();
                $("div.slate").hide();
                $("div.tab-" + index).show();
            }

        });

    });

Comment: but it is showing all three of the content sections on the page when first loaded then on the 2nd/3rd tab clicks it pulls in 1st/2nd content then when you click on 1st tab it is empty. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry index() is 0-based, so in the example the index needs to be incremented before it's used.